# radiobuttons (change condition to onclick)

Tags: java, android

In general have this screen:

[image]

How to put conditions from `OnClick` to `onCheckedChanged` (radiobutton). It works only with one variable `price_53_off` in OnClick, but I want when checked other radiobutton (500 gr.) program parses other variable (price_73_off) and calculate other cycle.

Some code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{
  ImageView plus;
  ImageView minus;
  TextView tvResult;
  TextView price;
  TextView price_53_off;
  TextView price_73_off;
  RadioGroup radioGroup_price;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    plus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    plus.setOnClickListener(this);
    minus= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    minus.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
    price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
    price_53_off = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_53_off);
    price_73_off = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_73_off);
    radioGroup_price = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup_price);

    radioGroup_price.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

         switch (checkedId) {
           case R.id.radioButton_250:
             price.setText("53");
             break;

           case R.id.radioButton_500:
             price.setText("73");
             break;
         }
       }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    int parse_quant;
    int parse_price_53;
    int num2 = 1;
    int result = 0;
    int resultprice=0;
    parse_quant = Integer.parseInt(tvResult.getText().toString());
    parse_price_53 = Integer.parseInt(price_53_off.getText().toString());

    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.plus:
        result = parse_quant + num2;
        resultcena= result*parse_price_53;
    }

    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.minus:
        result = parse_quant - num2;
        if (parse_quant==1){
          return;
        }
        resultprice= result*parse_price_53;
    }

    tvResult.setText( String.valueOf(result) );
    price.setText( String.valueOf(resultprice) );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `result` and `resultPrice` variables to be available in both `onCheckChanged` and `onClick`, you need to store them at the class level instead of local inside the `onClick` method.